# Exclude list of IDs from an array list in Java script

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, array-filter

I have two array one contains the list of ID that I want to remove from the employee array.

What is the best way to do it in Java script? I can use any ES6 syntaxes

```
{
  "excludeIDArray": [
    1,
    3,
    4
  ]
}



{
  "employee": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "joe"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "john"
    },
    {
      "id": "3",
      "name": "mike"
    },
    {
      "id": "4",
      "name": "alex"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "sean"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want the output to be an array which looks like

```
{
  "employee": [
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "john"
    },
    {
      "id": "5",
      "name": "sean"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: [Array.prototype.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and [Array.prototype.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: *"What is the best way"* .... what did you try ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use `Array.prototype.filter`, `Array.prototype.indexOf` and `parseInt` (for converting string IDs into numbers).

```js
const exc = {"excludeIDArray":[1,3,4]}
const inObj = {"employee":[{"id":"1","name":"joe"},{"id":"2","name":"john"},{"id":"3","name":"mike"},{"id":"4","name":"alex"},{"id":"5","name":"sean"}]}

const outObj = { 
  employee: inObj.employee.filter(e => exc.excludeIDArray.indexOf(parseInt(e.id, 10)) === -1)
}

console.log(outObj);
```

---

You could also use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) (if available) instead of `Array.prototype.indexOf` as it is certainly more readable

```
e => !exc.excludeIDArray.includes(parseInt(e.id, 10))
```

---

Another option is to convert your exclusion array into a [`Set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) which would allow for better (`O(1)`) performance

```js
const exc = {"excludeIDArray":[1,3,4]}
const inObj = {"employee":[{"id":"1","name":"joe"},{"id":"2","name":"john"},{"id":"3","name":"mike"},{"id":"4","name":"alex"},{"id":"5","name":"sean"}]}

const exclude = new Set(exc.excludeIDArray)
const outObj = {
  employee: inObj.employee.filter(e => !exclude.has(parseInt(e.id, 10)))
}
console.info(outObj)
```

Answer (score 2):

Uses a map for filtering instead of `indexOf` for faster linear time filtering

```js
var exclusion = {"excludeIDArray": [1, 3, 4]};

var data = {"employee":[{"id":"1","name":"joe"},{"id":"2","name":"john"},{"id":"3","name":"mike"},{"id":"4","name":"alex"},{"id":"5","name":"sean"}]};
 
var exclusionMap = {};
exclusion.excludeIDArray.forEach(excludeId=>{exclusionMap[excludeId] = 1});
var filteredEmployees = data.employee.filter(employee=>{return exclusionMap[employee.id] === undefined});
console.log(filteredEmployees);
```

Comment: Nice, especially if OP's arrays get bigger.